# Merge two columns from two tables into one

Tags: mysql, merge

I'm trying to sort by two different columns from two different tables.
This is the situtation:

I have 1 table 'shops' with a column called 'shopy', an INT column.
The other table is called 'infra' and has a column called 'y', also an INT.

I would like to select these two columns and sort by them both, so I will get a result like this:

```
       y
----------------
value from shopy
value from shopy
value from y
value from shopy
value from y
value from y
value from shopy
etc.
```

So that the shopy and y get merged and sorted by the values of them.

My question to you: is this possible?

Comment: Make us of `join` keyword on 2 table and add condition `order by` at the end of query.

Comment: with the **join** he can achieve to have the data in the same dataset, but not to mix it in the same column.

Comment: You need to do a union between the two tables, not a join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT shopy as y FROM shops
 UNION ALL
 SELECT y FROM infra
 ORDER BY y ASC
```

for Descending order write Order by y DESC.

Demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62884/1

Answer (score 0):

yes of course is possible and yes of course you can.

all you have to do is a temporary table with a column called whatever you want and insert the values of the 2 tables into the temporary table, in the same column.

at the end you only need to select from the teporary table ordering it as you want.

read the [tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-temporary-table/) posted here

Answer (score 0):

yes try this :if you want in descending order

```
SELECT <columnnane> FROM tableName
UNION ALL
SELECT <columnnane> FROM tablename
ORDER BY <columnnane> DESC
```

:if you want in ascending order:

```
SELECT <columnnane> FROM tableName
UNION ALL
SELECT <columnnane> FROM tablename
ORDER BY <columnnane>
```